# Control x-range of multiple subplots in matlab with UIControl

Tags: matlab, user-interface, animation

I'm trying to create a sliding window (with a slider) to view multiple subplots each of which is a long time series.

```
S=['set(gca,''xlim'',get(gcbo,''value'')+[0 ' num2str(chunkDuration) '])'];
h=uicontrol('style','slider','units','normalized','position',Newpos,...
    'callback',S,'min',0,'max',xmax-chunkDuration);
```

As written, this only causes the bottom plot to move. I understand that's because I set `gca`. However, changing `gcf` to `gca` won't help because that would try to set the `xlim` of figure instead of its children.

When I try

```
 kids = get(gcf,'Children')
 S=['set(kids,''xlim'',get(gcbo,''value'')+[0 ' num2str(chunkDuration) '])'];
```

I get the error:

```
 ??? Undefined function or variable 'kids'.
 ??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

So, why doesn't the above work?

Even after a substantial [change in approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359231/too-many-input-arguments-to-uicontrol-callback), the problems remain.

Comment: It is encouraged to ask a new question if you are having a different problem. If there is an answer that solved your problem please accept it and ask a new question consisting of your "big edit".

Comment: There was no answer that solved my problem. I read more and tried a different approach. I'll move the 'big edit' to a new question.

Comment: Just as a reminder; if you solved your problem on your own you can post an answer and accept it. That way, future users will benefit from your approach.

Comment: I wish I solved it. :-) I do, I will. (I have done that in the past.)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code you try to use a variable named `subplot_handles`. The error arises because this variable is undefined at the time you try to use it.

### **Update**:

Is there a reason why you are saving your `set` commands as `String`s?  I suspect that its completely un-needed.

When you create your subplots try storing the handles to the axes created by the subplot objects.

```
ax(1) = subplot(311);
ax(2) = subplot(312);
ax(3) = subplot(313);
```

Later on you can set the limits for all `subplot`s using:

```
set(ax, 'XLim', get(gcbo,'value') + [0  num2str(chunkDuration)] );
```

Comment: Nope- it's defined and prints out a series of handles (floats).

Comment: sorry the variable that trips the error is `kids` not `subplot_handles`, that was an earlier version.