# Too many input arguments to uicontrol callback

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am trying to write a scroll bar that changes the x-range of many subplots at the same time.

```
kids = get(gcf,'Children');
 h=uicontrol('style','slider',...
'units','normalized','position',Newpos,...
'callback',{@slide_axes,kids},'min',0,'max',xmax-chunkDuration);
```

Update_axes is defined in the same file:

```
function slide_axes(h)
 set(h,'xlim',get(gcbo,'value')+[0 20000]);
```

end

However, I get the error:

```
??? Error using plot_scroll>slide_axes
Too many input arguments.

??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

I read on the FEX that callback may pass two arguments to any callback function. However, when I changed the signature of `slide_axes` to `slide_axes(h,evt)` the error remains.

Comment: Is your callback definition supposed to be 'callback',{@slide_axes,kids} ?

Comment: Yes, that's a bad cut and paste job- not an error in the actual code. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments you are passing (`h` and `evt`) are MATLAB defaults. If you want to pass additional arguments to your callback function you need to write them after `h` and `evt`. Like this:

```
function slide_axes(h, evt, k)
    % k is kids.
end
```

Comment: Would you believe, I just figured that out!